# my mapdispatch to props is automatically calling

Tags: reactjs, redux

Post component:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import './post.styles.scss';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { requestContents } from '../../redux/post/post.actions';

  class Post extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){   
    }
    render(){
      return (
          <div>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      onRequestContents : dispatch(requestContents())
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      posts: state.post.posts,
      isPending: state.post.isPending
    }
  }
```

User component:

```
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Post)

  import React from 'react';
  import './user.styles.scss';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { requestUsers } from '../../redux/user/user.actions';

  class User extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount(){
      this.props.onRequestUsers();
    }

    render(){
      return (
         <div>
        </div>
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      onRequestUsers: () => dispatch(requestUsers())
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      users: state.user.users,
      isPending: state.user.isPending
    }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User)
```

Here I am using **redux** with React.
In user component i am calling **onRequestUsers** inside **componentWillMount()**
but in post component i am not calling **onRequestContents** inside **componentWillMount()**

But still how it is calling and display in my **redux-logger**

I am calling **mapDispatchToProps** only inside user component

Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `requestContents` in your `mDTP` call:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onRequestContents: dispatch(requestContents())
  }
}
```

That's what those two parens do:

```
requestContents()
```

Omit them:

```
onRequestContents: dispatch(requestContents)
```

That said: there's something odd with your function. Normally you'd `mDTP` with a function, e.g.,

```
onRequestContents: () => dispatch(requestContents())
```

(Used when you need to pass parameters, like an event.)

Comment: @soubhagyapradhan I'm not sure how; maybe `dispatch` will call a function if given one? I don't know if I've ever done it like that.